# Calcular os segundos da consulta

Tags: jquery, query, jquery-datatables, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

Como calcular os segundos da consulta abaixo:

```
SELECT I.DATA_REGISTRO, F.DATA_REGISTRO, I.ENDTOEND, F.TIPO, F.ISPB_PAGADORA, F.ISPB_RECEBEDORA
FROM PAGAMENTO_INICIO I WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN PAGAMENTO_FINAL F
    ON I.ENDTOEND = F.ENDTOEND
WHERE ISPB_PAGADORA = '68900810'
    AND TIPO = 'externo'
```

Comment: Informe o SGBD.

Answer (score -4):

A julgar pelo uso do [nolock] você está usando sql server. Se é esse o caso basta fazer:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO

SELECT I.DATA_REGISTRO, F.DATA_REGISTRO, I.ENDTOEND, F.TIPO, F.ISPB_PAGADORA, F.ISPB_RECEBEDORA
FROM PAGAMENTO_INICIO I WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN PAGAMENTO_FINAL F
    ON I.ENDTOEND = F.ENDTOEND
WHERE ISPB_PAGADORA = '68900810'
    AND TIPO = 'externo'
GO
```